# Having trouble accessing object's instance variable in Perl SOAP server code

Tags: perl, soap

I'm working through example SOAP client/server code using SOAP::Transport::HTTP:Daemon and SOAP::Lite, and I've noticed that I cannot access an instance variable declared in an object's new() method. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what (although it has been years since I was a half-decent Perl programmer).

Here's my server:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use lib '/a/valid/directory/modules';

use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;

my $port = 9810;

my $dispatchers = {
  'urn:remote_call' => 'ExampleLibrary::MyExample'
};

my $daemon = SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Daemon
  -> new (LocalAddr => 'localhost', LocalPort => $port)
  -> dispatch_with($dispatchers)
  -> on_action(sub {return})
  ;

print "Connect to SOAP server at ", $daemon->url, "\n";
$daemon->handle;
```

Here's my client (located in a directory specified in the server's use lib line, modules/ExampleLibrary/MyExample.pm):

```
package ExampleLibrary::MyExample;

use vars qw(@ISA);
@ISA = qw(Exporter SOAP::Server::Parameters);

use SOAP::Lite;

sub new {
  my($class, %args) = @_;
  my $self = bless({}, $class);
  $self->{somevar} = 'somedata';
  return $self;
}

sub remote_call {
  my $self = shift;
  my $envelope = pop;
  # Swap out return statements and the data is returned correctly
  # return SOAP::Data->type('xml' => 'foo');
  return SOAP::Data->type('xml' => "$self->{somevar}");
}

1;
```

I'm sure I'm hitting the client correctly--I can put in static text in the remote_call's return statement (the commented out code) and see it--but the object data specified as $self->{somevar} is never visible, with or without quotes. (I'm using SoapUI to hit the server.)

Does anyone see what I'm missing? (Oh, I'm using Perl v5.10.1 on Cygwin.)

Thanks...

Comment: In `remote_call`, throw in a `Carp::confess( 'GAK!' )` and that should give you a summary of what is being passed in to the sub. `SOAP::Lite` has a tendency to use things in ways you might not expect.

Comment: @Axeman: Sadly, I only get a <faultstring>Undefined subroutine &amp;Carp::Confess called at...</faultstring> error (and I did add a use Carp; line).

Comment: @QJ, what about server logs? You mean that you are getting that back in the client. That's fine. But what is it printing to the log? The remedy for that is `use Carp;` some where at the top of the script.

Comment: @Axeman: I had use Carp lines in both the server and the client. And, since the server is only the roll-your-own server shown in the code listing, there aren't really server logs to check. (Unless, perhaps, I am unaware of something.) Btw, I appreciate your responses. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The docs say

```
  dispatch_with({
    URI => MODULE,        # 'http://www.soaplite.com/' => 'My::Class',
    SOAPAction => MODULE, # 'http://www.soaplite.com/method' => 'Another::Class',
    URI => object,        # 'http://www.soaplite.com/obj' => My::Class->new,
  })
```

You have

```
my $dispatchers = {
  'urn:remote_call' => 'ExampleLibrary::MyExample'
};
```

maybe that should be

```
my $dispatchers = {
  'urn:remote_call' => 'ExampleLibrary::MyExample->new'
};
```

Otherwise (I speculate that) your method may be being invoked as a static method not as an instance method (no instance having been instantiated).

P.S. The absence of single-quotes for the object instantiation string in the docs puzzles me as it suggests that a single instance is used to handle all requests (and that seems wrong to me) but maybe that is indeed what this experimental feature needs and you should omit the single quotes too.

Comment: Sadly, using ExampleLibrary::MyExample->new results in the following return: <faultstring>Failed to access class (ExampleLibrary::MyExample->new): Can't locate object method "new" via package "ExampleLibrary::MyExample" at (eval 100) line 2.</faultstring>

Answer (score 1):

I got this working after tweaking the code a bit from @RedGrittyBrick's suggestion (or perhaps it's exactly what he suggested and I just didn't understand it). Thanks also to @Axeman--you came back multiple times to try and help out--I appreciate that very much. I put comments in the server to indicate the two lines that fixed things.

Here's the revised server:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use lib '/a/valid/directory/modules';

use ExampleLibrary::MyExample;    # new!
use SOAP::Transport::HTTP;

my $port = 9810;

my $dispatchers = {
  # new--no quotes around the hash value
  'urn:remote_call' => ExampleLibrary::MyExample->new
};

my $daemon = SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Daemon
  -> new (LocalAddr => 'localhost', LocalPort => $port)
  -> dispatch_with($dispatchers)
  -> on_action(sub {return})
  ;

print "Connect to SOAP server at ", $daemon->url, "\n";
$daemon->handle;
```

Here's the revised client. Really, the only changes were to put localtime() calls in so that I could verify that variables set in new() remained unchanged over the lifetime of the server.

```
package ExampleLibrary::MyExample;

use vars qw(@ISA);
@ISA = qw(Exporter SOAP::Server::Parameters);

use SOAP::Lite;

sub new {
  my($class, %args) = @_;
  my $self = bless({}, $class);
  $self->{'somevar'} = localtime();
  return $self;
}

sub remote_call {
  my $self = shift;
  my $envelope = pop;
  $now = localtime();
  return SOAP::Data->type('xml' => "now = $now, started at $self->{somevar}");
}

1;
```

Comment: Hi QJ. Can you please provide an example of SOAP client use ?